# Compare date to today does not work

Tags: php

I want to display a text if the date in the database matches today's date.

```
$userdate = date("m/d/Y", strtotime($rr['last_login']));
    $today = date("m/d/Y");

    if ($userdate==$today){
        echo "<test>";
    }
```

Even if it is today's date, the records never echo out the  string.
Interestingly, if I change it to

```
if ($userdate!=$today){
```

it also does not display the `<test>`.

Comment: it seems u did not post the full question.Can u do that?

Comment: What is the value of `$rr['last_login']`?

Comment: Don't use / to saperate use - this will help

Comment: @MousamiRoul it doesn't matter in this case as they are comparing strings

Comment: I downvoted as you seem to have walked away without answering question in the comments. You should always stay around to answer those questions as the window for you getting help gets smaller as each minute passes.

Comment: @JohnConde I did not "walk away".  I clicked the big blue button that said "answer your question" and that's where I provided the update.  I am not sure what downvoting means or what the implications are.  If I always get an answer to my question, what exactly is the meaning behind the points? The correct answer did not come in these comments actually (for example the value of $rr['last_login'] was not relevant) -  they came in an answer below by mehedi-pstu2k9 who provided the correct solution.  Ironically, his correct answer has zero points.

Answer (score 0):

My bad!  I was not trying to echo out any html thing.  The < brackets were just random characters.  I changed it to "test" and now it works.  Sorry for the < > characters causing  confusion!

Answer (score -1):

Since this is PHP, one would assume you're looking at the result in a browser, which will interpret the "<test>" as an HTML tag, and thus it will ignore it. Try changing the "echo" to simply echo "test<br>";

Also, if you are always dealing with a database, you could also use this:

```
if (substr($rr['last_login'], 0, 10) == date('Y-m-d'))
    echo "test<br />\n";
```